# apache tomcat error in creating enhanved for loop

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

i am trying to make combo boxes with list of values but an error occurs in the enhanced loop ... my code is

```
<body>
<% List<String> sexList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("sexList"); %>
<% List<String> maritalStatus = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("maritalStatus"); %>
 <form method="GET" action='FilterMembers'>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Genre:</td>
            <td><select name="sex">
                <%for(String item : sexList) { %>
                    <option value="<%=item%>"><%=item %></option><%}%>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Marital Status:</td>
            <td><select name="mStatus">
                <%for(String item : maritalStatus) { %>
                    <option value="<%=item%>"><%=item %></option><%}%>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
      <table>
     </body>
     </form>
```

Comment: OK, I see the code, but what's the error?

Comment: What version of tomcat and you shouldn't be using scriptlets.

Comment: an exception occured in the enhanced for loop

Comment: @ElliottFrisch tomcat 7

Comment: Are you sure `maritalStatus` and `sexList` are not null?

Comment: You've got a close `</form>` tag after your `</body>` and an open `<table>` instead of a close `</table>` before the `</body>`. Not sure if these are problems in your code, or just in the sample you've provided.

Comment: It's tough to understand the problem if you don't provide the error with the stack trace. Just copy and paste it into your question.